# Antonym of preventive

Tags: adjectives

Suitable word which has meaning “taking care of agricultural plants after the damage (affected by virus or some other insects)has happened”
Taking steps before damage happens is “preventive” then what is the antonym for “preventive”

Comment: "Prevention is better than cure", so I suppose the antonym is _curative_?

Answer (score 4):

Preventive (*prevent* + *-ive*) is an adjective formed from a verb ***prevent*** and *suffix* ***-ive*** (*-ive* is word-forming element making adjectives from verbs). Here, prevent means an "act in anticipation of", it comes from Latin *praeventus*, past participle of *praevenire* meaning "*come before*, *anticipate*, *hinder*". So, preventive actions is taken **before** [*something bad*] may happen.

The *action* to restore the current state of [*something*] to its previously healthy state **after** [*something bad*] happens must be ***remedial*** *action*. Remedial is an adjective formed from a noun *remedy.* Whereas, remedy is *re-* and *mederi*,  *mederi* means "to heal". Unlike *-ive*, *re* is a *prefix* meaning "back to the original place; again, anew, once more," also with a sense of "undoing".

The word which acts as an antonym to *preventive* is **remedial.** It means, "curing, relieving, affording a remedy," from Late Latin remedialis "healing, curing," from Latin remedium "a cure, remedy, medicine, antidote, that which restores health.

So, in summary, *Preventive* action is taken **before** [*something bad*] may happen ***and*** *Remedial* action is taken **after** [*something bad*] happens.

[Merriam Webster defines 1](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/remedial) remedial as:  intended as a **remedy**.

**Remedy**: a medicine, application, or treatment that relieves or cures a disease

[Oxford dictionary defines 1](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/remedial) remedial as: Giving or intended as a remedy or cure.

Answer (score 0):

There are the words "**reparative**" or "**reparatory**" that can be used as an antonyms for "preventive".

> It is best to employ *preventive* measures before ***reparative***
>   measures become necessary.

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/reparatory